# Oracle query to link records from same table which maps to mapping table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Apologies for the horrible question title,not sure how to articulate it better.

So to start out.

```
**Table Dummy_Table**
id      description     filter_key
 1      Test Record1    filterkey1
 2      Test Record2    filterkey1
 3      Test Record1    filterkey2
 4      Test Record2    filterkey2

The records with filterkey1 map to a table like this

**Table Mapping_table**
Dummy_Table_id   someother_key (one(Dummy_Table_id) to many(someother_key)
  1                  x
  1                  y
  1                  z
  1                  r
  2                  y
  2                  r
```

Now : In a query I map the id's to each other in the Dummy_Table using the description,so I end up with a resultset like this

```
id_for_filter_key1         id_for_filterkey2
      1                          3
      2                          4
```

Ok,thats all good and well,it's the next step I'm having a issue with.I need to add records to **Table Mapping_table** which should end up looking like this

```
**Table Mapping_table**
 Dummy_Table_id   someother_key
      3                x
      3                y
      3                z
      3                r
      4                y
      4                r
```

So in essence whatever the id is for filterKey1 I would like to apply it's someother_key to the id's with filterkey2 (filterKey1 and filterkey2  relate to each other with their descriptions)

Now I don't know if I'm over complicating this.I'll tell you what my problem is.

I have records in the database with filterkey1 which map to the mapping table.Afterwords I added the records with filterkey2.These rows are duplicates just with another filter key.Now I need to apply the same mappings to the records with filterkey2

Changing the table structure is not a option atm.I need to give the DBA a insert query to achieve this.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to explain the logic behind those letters.

Answer (score 0):

This query gives missing values:

```
SELECT d.id_for_filterkey2, m.someother_key
FROM Mapping_table m
JOIN Dummy_Table d ON m.Dummy_Table_id = d.id_for_filter_key1
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/61ddfe/2

When we have missing values, then we can merge them into Mapping_table:

```
MERGE INTO Mapping_table m
USING(  copy-the-above-query-and-paste-it-here) x
ON (x.id_for_filterkey2 = m.Dummy_Table_id)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT( Dummy_Table_id,   someother_key ) 
VALUES( x.id_for_filterkey2, x.someother_key );
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d74304/3

Comment: Looks promising,will try it out when I get to work.Thanks